# VSCode: run without debugging doesn't run whole javascript code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to run this code:

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange'];

function filterItems(query) {
  return fruits.filter(function(el) {
      return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  })
}

console.log(filterItems('ap')); // ['apple', 'grapes']
console.log(filterItems('an')); // ['banana', 'mango', 'orange']
```

This code runs as expected writting in terminal "node index.js", but when hit in vscode `Run -> run without debugging` vscode shows its debug console and doesn't run the last line: `console.log(filterItems('an')); // ['banana', 'mango', 'orange']`
Can you tell me why this happens, since i'm not using breakpoints?

This is what debug console shows when i run without debugging (Same result if i just run "F5"):

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe d:\andysierra\Descargas\tempies\aprendiendoNodeJS1\index.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57611/05f98c8f-7811-467c-8c0c-bb47e304b1bf
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Process exited with code 0
(2) ['apple', 'grapes']
index.js:12
No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'
```